# Footnote Citation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I'm putting a science related presentation together with the `beamer` class and I'd like to add citations as footnotes on the relevant slides. I've got the `biblatex` package running and am using the `\footcite` command which does a nice job. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear `biblatex` will put the journal, volume number, page number information in the foot note citation. Does anyone know how to get this stuff to show up in the footnote?

With the `style=authortitle` option selected I get footnote citations like:

> Magde, Elson, and Webb, Thermodynamic Fluctuations in a Reacting System - Measurement by Fluorescence Correlation Spectroscopy".

But I'd really like something like this in the footnote

> Magde, Elson, and Webb, Phys. Rev. Lett. 29, 705 (1972)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion of `\footfullcite`. That does a nice job of getting all the info in the citation. I tied the suggestion of Audery but get an error. Would this command go in the preamble or somewhere else?

Comment: @theonlyedward You can define the command in the preamble and then use it like `\footcite`: `\footlessfullcite{<entrykey>}`. I had an error in my comment, though. It should be: `\newrobustcmd*{\footlessfullcite}{\AtNextCite{\renewbibmacro{title}{}\renewbibmacro{in:}{}}\footfullcite}`. (`\clearfield` is an entry-specific command and therefore would only work with something like `\AtNextCitekey`.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. That got rid of the title but left the authors and journal info. Excellent, thanks!

Comment: In conjunction with the biblatex-chem, chem-acs style that works really well. In beamer, any idea how to get foot note citations to appear at the bottom of the page when they're called inside the block environment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you may want to to try `\footfullcite` instead of `\footcite`.

[From Audrey] Adding the line:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\footlessfullcite}{\AtNextCite{\renewbibmacro{title}{}\renewbibmacro{in:}{}}\footfullcite}
```

in the preamble and the using `\footlessfullcite{<entry key>}` results in a nice footnote citation.