# Undesired Placement of Footnotes in Blocks

Tags: beamer, biblatex, positioning, footnotes

Depending on the theme of a `beamer-document`, footnotes will either be placed inside or outside of a block-environment. It would like to do combine a style, which places the footnotes *inside* a block-environment e.g.  `Copenhagen`, with footnotes *outside* of blocks. Strangely, no option I have tried for `\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[option]` seems to do that - whether I used `default, circles, rectangles,`nor `inmargin`. Is there any other way to tell beamer that footnotes should be placed at the bottom of the frame?

On the left you can see the desired result with theme `Berlin`, both footnotes are at the bottom of the frame. On the right you see the the outcome with theme `Copenhagen` that unfortunately places one footnote inside the block-environment, which I would like avoid.

[image]

**UPDATE:** So here is my new MWE with some code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45406/footnotes-disappear-when-using-overlays-in-beamer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp, backend=biber, citetracker=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}
% Citation number in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{A frame}
\begin{block}{Classic theory}
  As we already know from classic theory\sfcite{reese}, ...
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Fact 1
    \item Fact 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{block}
Now there are some new developments\sfcite{bertram} challenging the classic view.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Update 24.02.**

I found that in `beamerbaseboxes.sty` this minipage seems to be responsible for the footnote inside the block-environment.

```
\newcommand\beamerboxesrounded[2][]{%
  [...]
  % line 120
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox\bgroup\begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
  \vskip2pt%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@lower}%
  \colorlet{beamerstructure}{upper.bg}%
  \colorlet{structure}{upper.bg}%
  %\color{.}%
}

\def\endbeamerboxesrounded{%
  \end{minipage}\egroup%
```

Removing the minipage is not a good solution though, since it messes up the layout. Also taking `\end{minipage}\egroup%` inside `\newcommand\beamerboxesrounded` takes the footnote to the bottom of the slide, but messes up the layout.

Comment: Do you *really* need more than one footnote in a frame?

Comment: @egreg, well I use footnotes for showing references in a frame and sometimes there are more than one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a very similar problem to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44230/4427)

You need to use `\footnotemark` inside the `block` environment and `\foocitetext{reese}` immediately after it:

```
\begin{frame}{A frame}
  \begin{block}{Classic theory}
    As we already know from classic theory\footnotemark, ...
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Fact 1
      \item Fact 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}\footcitetext{reese}
Now there are some new developments\footcite{bertram} challenging the classic view.
\end{frame}
```

For your particular style, this basic idea can be incorporated into `\sfcite`. Here footnotes outside blocks are set using the `\AfterEndEnvironment` hook from the etoolbox package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,citetracker=true,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcitetext}
  [\let\thefootnote\relax\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\mkbibbrackets{\thefield{labelnumber}}%
   \addnbspace%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
\newtoggle{cbx@blockcite}

\renewcommand{\@makefntext}[1]{%
  \noindent\normalfont\@thefnmark#1}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifciteseen
     {\ifnumequal{\value{page}}{\csuse{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}}
       {}
       {\ifnumequal{\value{framenumber}}{\csuse{cbx@frame@\thefield{entrykey}}}
          {\usebibmacro{sfcite}}
          {}}}
     {\usebibmacro{sfcite}}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@page@\thefield{entrykey}}{\value{page}}%
  \csnumgdef{cbx@frame@\thefield{entrykey}}{\value{framenumber}}%
  \xappto\cbx@citehook{%
    \noexpand\footfullcitetext{\thefield{entrykey}}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \iftoggle{cbx@blockcite}
    {}
    {\cbx@citehook%
     \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{block}{\global\toggletrue{cbx@blockcite}}

\def\metabox#1{\edef\theprevdepth{\the\prevdepth}\nointerlineskip
  \vbox to0pt{#1\vss}\prevdepth=\theprevdepth}

\AfterEndEnvironment{block}
  {\metabox{%
     \global\togglefalse{cbx@blockcite}%
     \cbx@citehook%
     \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}}

\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[b]{First Frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item First citation.\sfcite{reese} Recurrent citation.\sfcite{reese}
  \item Second citation.\sfcite{springer}
  \item Recurrent citation.\sfcite{springer}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[b]{Second Frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
  \item Third citation.\sfcite{glashow}
  \item Recurrent citation.\sfcite{reese,springer,glashow}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Third frame}
\begin{block}{Block title}
Recurrent citation.\sfcite{reese} New citation.\sfcite{companion}
\end{block}
New citation.\sfcite{bertram}
Recurrent citation.\sfcite{bertram,companion}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are willing to track footnotes manually, a simpler approach is preferable. Add *only* the following in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}}
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\footfullcitetext}[\mkbibfootnotetext]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Then input your frame as

```
\begin{frame}{A frame}
  \begin{block}{Classic theory}
    As we already know from classic theory\footnotemark\ ...
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Fact 1
      \item Fact 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}\footfullcitetext{reese}

Now there are some new developments\footfullcite{bertram} challenging the classic view. 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: you're right this solves the problem for the provided MWE. I originally wanted to combine the bibstyle from here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45406/footnotes-disappear-when-using-overlays-in-beamer with the footnotes. To keep the example simple, I didn't include the relevant bibliography code, which I probably should have done. With the bibliography code, it doesn't really work well, adding a 1 inside the block and [1] outside.

Comment: @maetra Please, make a full MWE

Comment: I hope the MWE makes it clearer now.

Comment: everything works fine for two citations. Although there is one drawback: If there is just `\sfootnotemark` `\sfcitetext` and no `\sfcite` afterwards no footnote is printed.

Comment: I'm afraid that some better surgery has to be done.

Comment: well I guess at the moment I just "*really* need more than one footnote in a frame"

Comment: @egreg `\sfcitetext` needs to expand `\cbx@citehook` and reset it to `\empty`. That can be done with the wrapper argument in `\DeclareCiteCommand`.

Comment: @Audrey I'll tried adding `\let\cbx@citehook=\empty` as the wrapper argument in `DeclareCiteCommand`, but I didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Audrey Feel free to add an answer.

Comment: @maetra It doesn't work because `\cbx@citehook` needs to be expanded first.

Comment: @egreg Mind if I just edit your answer at some point? The approach would be identical.

Comment: @Audrey Please do. There is another point: the `\sfcitetext` command enters horizontal mode and it shouldn't.

Comment: @egreg Done. I streamlined the citation commands. I'm no good with modes, so I just slapped the code in a vbox using code from one of you previous answers. Please edit further as you see fit.

Comment: @Audrey great work, I would never have come up with this. I am not trying to be nitpicking, but there is just one more thing. Now there is some extra space between the footnotes and which I would rather get rid of. Additionally I think you left out `backend=biber` in your MWE, at least for me I didnt work without biber.

Comment: @maetra Spacing should be tighter now. I typically use the default backend for solutions that don't *need* biber to work. You can of course use biber as the backend if you like.

Comment: @Audrey looks great now, I played around with a bit more and tried to combine it with your code `\newrobustcmd*{\footlessfullcite}{\AtNextCite{\renewbibmacro{title}{}\renewbibmacro{in:}{}}\sfcite}` from here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29069/footnote-citation-in-beamer. For citations outside of boxes everything works fine, inside boxes the title is still printed. Getting the title ommission to work with citations inside boxes would just be the icing on the cake.

Comment: @maetra Hold the phone. I think I see what you mean now. Just add `\AtEveryCite{\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}\renewbibmacro*{title}{}}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Audrey I am sorry for the confusion. Yes, with boxes I meant blocks and I want all the footnote citations outside blocks. What I was trying to say: If try to ommit the title of a reference in the footnote, `footlessfullcite` works as expected, if the citation was made outside of a block. If I use `footlessfullcite` inside a block, the footnote is printed at the bottom of the frame not the block, which is perfectly fine. Just in this case the reference contains the title of the citation, which I would like to omit.

Comment: @egreg: you're answer is great. But there is only one problem. Using that, when I want to use `\footnote` the numeric which should be as a superscript in footnote is simply stand beside the text (like this: 1Here). Would you help on that?

Comment: @Amin Difficult to say without seeing an example of code.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446521/footnote-cite-in-beamer-in-ieee-style-with-some-attributes

Comment: @egreg: I have a question. How we can make the superscript form to be a normal citation (just like inline with the text)? Please let me know. Thanks.