# beamer column footnote produces format lose.

Tags: beamer, margins, footnotes

Using the following code

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2001},
    title = {First Article Title Apha AAAAAAAAAAAAA AAA AA AA AA A AAA A A A AAAA}
}
@misc{A02,
    author = {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2002},
    title = {Second Article Title  Beta BBB B B B BBBB BBBBBB BBBBB BBBBB B B B BBBBB BBB BB}
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage     [   style=numeric-comp,
                            autocite=superscript, % apply options here.
                            sortcites,
                            backend=bibtex
                        ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{scalefnt,lmodern}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usetheme{Warsaw}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction} 

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide with references at the bottom}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5cm}
        \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=.5\textwidth]{mypicture} 
        \end{figure}        
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> in A happens that aa aaaaa aa\footnotemark[1]
\item<1-> and aslo that A aaa a aaa a a aaaa aaa aaaaa aaa\footnotemark [1]
\item<1-> 5\textsuperscript{th} cause of bb bbbbb\footnotemark[2]
\item<1-> 1\textsuperscript{th} cause of bbb bbb bb\footnotemark[2] 
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\footnotetext[1]{\fullcite{A01}}
\footnotetext[2]{\fullcite{A02}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide with references at the bottom}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{5cm}
        \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=.5\textwidth]{mypicture} 
        \end{figure}        
\end{column}
\begin{column}{5cm}
\begin{minipage}[T]{\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> in A happens that aa aaaaa aa\footnotemark[1]
\item<1-> and aslo that A aaa a aaa a a aaaa aaa aaaaa aaa\footnotemark [1]
\item<1-> 5\textsuperscript{th} cause of bb bbbbb\footnotemark[2]
\item<1-> 1\textsuperscript{th} cause of bbb bbb bb\footnotemark[2] 
\end{itemize}
\footnotetext[1]{\fullcite{A01}}
\footnotetext[2]{\fullcite{A02}}
\end{minipage}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When placing the footnotes to the right column to let the left column free the references end up out of the slide as can be seen in the picture. Why is this happening isn't it supposed to be taken care by using `minipage`? Or is the problem that the footnote environment takes the margins from somewhere else? Is there any way to visualize which margins are the environments for a particular slide?

[image]

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44217 and http://http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45437 but I insist citations looks very ugly.

Comment: Well I do agree that citations in slides they don't look cool at all, but if you have to through some numbers that have nothing to do with your research you have to sustain such numbers somehow. Reference to medical pathology studies seems a good option. I hope that after the 4th slide I will have no more references to place.