# Footnote position in Beamer (beamerthemeshadow package)

Tags: beamer

I have the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
%\usetheme{Hannover}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usetheme{boxes}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle<presentation>{\hfill Heading \footnote{footnote 1}}
    \begin{block}{This is a block w\footnote{footnote 2}}
        Some text 1 \\ Some text 2 \\ Some text 3 \footnote{footnote 3}
    \end{block}
    Some text 4 \footnote{footnote 4}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that, the footnotes on title, block title and block content do not appear at the bottom of frame. How can I do that? I also need numerical numbering order.

Also, I have another question: In frame title, I used `\hfill` to move it. What is a better way?

Regards.
[image: footnote problem]

Comment: This seems to be similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/undesired-placement-of-footnotes-in-blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `footnotemark` and `footnotetext` to correct this.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
%\usetheme{Hannover}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usetheme{boxes}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle<presentation>{\hfill Heading \footnotemark[1]} \footnotetext[1]{footnote 1}
    \begin{block}{This is a block w\footnotemark[2]}
        Some text 1 \\ Some text 2 \\ Some text 3 \footnotemark[3]
    \end{block}\footnotetext[2]{footnote 2} \footnotetext[3]{footnote 3}
    Some text 4 \footnote[4]{footnote 4}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```