# footnote cite in Beamer in IEEE style with some attributes

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, footnotes

I am trying to use citation in footnote in Beamer. I have tried quite many examples in answers in `tex.stackexchange`, but each of them has some problems. There is one great answer by @egreg [Undesired Placement of Footnotes in Blocks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/undesired-placement-of-footnotes-in-blocks/45625?noredirect=1#comment1121622_45625])[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/undesired-placement-of-footnotes-in-blocks/45625?noredirect=1#comment1121622_45625) but it has 4th problem. What I want to see is that:

1. To be in IEEE style;
2. When citing insiding a block, the reference as a footnote must be outside the block (not inside the block);
3. Do not repeatedly print the reference in foot note when there are several citation to the same reference;
4. Does not have conflict with \footnote

Thanks for your help.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%add  a sample .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibexample.bib}
 @article{sigfridsson,
  title = {Four-dimensional flow {MRI} using spiral acquisition},
  volume = {68},
  number = {4},
  journal = {Magnetic Resonance in Medicine},
  author = {Sigfridsson, Andreas and Petersson, Sven and Carlhäll, Carl-Johan 
  and Ebbers, Tino},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {1065--1073}
 }
\end{filecontents}

% ===================================================================
\usepackage[style=ieee,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibexample.bib}
%=============================================================

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{1}

    \begin{block}{definition}
        There is a special type of non-stationary stochastic 
 processes\footfullcite{sigfridsson} when their statistical properties vary 
periodically\footnote{element} with time called cyclostationary processes 
\footfullcite{sigfridsson}.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what changes need to be done to fulfil your requirement 1.

Comment: @samcarter: actually it is fulfilled in this example. I meant all of them should be satisfied. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 3? Does that mean that you essentially want two levels of footnotes: One for normal footnotes and one for citations? In other document classes one could cook something up with `manyfoot` or the like, but as far as I know none of these solutions is compatible with `beamer`.

Comment: @moewe: I meant if there is one reference paper that should be noted twice or more in one page, then there should be only one print of citation in footnote without repetition to the same reference.Actually, in your answer it is okay.

Comment: A sorry, I confused point 3 and 4. I actually mean to ask about 4.

Comment: @moewe: yes, I mean that normally works for a footnote. Otherwise, what should I do when I need to make simple footnote? In your answer, the output for me is like this: 1Here which should be 1 as superscript..

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit of manual intervention, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%add  a sample .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibexample.bib}
 @article{sigfridsson,
  title = {Four-dimensional flow {MRI} using spiral acquisition},
  volume = {68},
  number = {4},
  journal = {Magnetic Resonance in Medicine},
  author = {Sigfridsson, Andreas and Petersson, Sven and Carlhäll, Carl-Johan 
  and Ebbers, Tino},
  year = {2012},
  pages = {1065--1073}
 }
\end{filecontents}

% ===================================================================
\usepackage[style=ieee,citetracker=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibexample.bib}
%=============================================================

\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{1}
    \begin{block}{definition}
        There is a special type of non-stationary stochastic 
 processes\footnotemark{} when their statistical properties vary 
periodically\footnotemark{} with time called cyclostationary processes\footnotemark[1].
  \end{block}
  \setcounter{footnote}{1}
  \footnotetext{element}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{1}
  \footnotetext{\fullcite{sigfridsson}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]