# Edit footnote citation in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

Based on [Footnote Citation in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29069/footnote-citation-in-beamer) I was able to produce a citation that is Authors, Journal Year. By I was hoping to fix two things in the example below to match the `\footcite` case:

1) I would like the color to be black

2) I would like the year to be in parenthesis

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,compress]{beamer}

%Beamer Settings
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}


%BIB File
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{MWE.bib}
@article{ref1,
author = "Appleton, W. and Anderson, Z. and Almeirim, P.",
title = "This is the title of this article, which as you can see, is very long and takes up too much space in the footnote.",
journal = "Journal of Interesting Things",
year = 2013}
@book{ref2,
author = "Burger, J.",
title = "The title of the Book is this",
publisher = "Public Publishing Publishers",
year = 2014
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authortitle-dw,addyear=true]{biblatex} % For .bib references
\addbibresource{MWE.bib}  % The bibliography file
\newrobustcmd*{\footlessfullcite}{\AtNextCite{\renewbibmacro{title}{}\renewbibmacro{in:}{}}\footfullcite}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example in Beamer}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is an example of text.\pause{}
        \item Here is the second text that contains a reference\footlessfullcite{ref1} in the middle of the sentence.\pause{}
        \item Here is another reference at the end of the sentence\footcite{ref2}.
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For the colours, try `\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}`

Comment: See also [How to change the color of bibitems?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225218/35864), [Beamer bibliography color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22545/35864), [Changing the appearance of citations with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297639/35864)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @samcarter and the answer in [Trying to understand the renewbibmacro and DeclareFieldFormat construct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191204/trying-to-understand-the-renewbibmacro-and-declarefieldformat-construct) I got the effect I desired by adding the following lines after `\newrobustcmd`:

```
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=black}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{date}{(#1)}
```